# When a user mentions the owner the bot should say you're not allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make it when a user is tagged (eg. `MyNameJeff#0001`), the bot will automatically respond with you're not allowed to mention them and delete their message.

I tried searching for an event that could handle this but haven't found anything useful so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the collection [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) includes the guild owner's ID with the [`has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) method. A simple `if (message.mentions.users.has(message.guild.ownerId))` will work for you:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.mentions.users.has(message.guild.ownerId)) {
    message.channel.send('You are not allowed to mention the owner!');
    message.delete();
  }
});
```